# Printing substring in text file (output has been printing entire file)

Tags: python, string, list, substring

I am atempting to print any lines in a text file with the words *Network* or *Diagnostic*. However, the output prints all lines in the file. For this script, I need it just print lines with the above words. 
    import os

```
os.system("NET START > c:\\temp\\mypythonfiles\\currservices.txt")
path1="c:\\temp\\mypythonfiles\\currservices.txt"
list1=[]
substr1="Network"
substr2="Diagnostic"
tstring=substr1+substr2
stop=open("c:\\temp\\mypythonfiles\\currservices.txt","rt")
with open(path1,"rt") as file :
    for line in file:
       list1.append(line)
         if line.find(tstring):
            for line in list1:
                print("Service found:",line, sep=" ")

stop.close()
```

Here's the output:

```
Service found: The command completed successfully.

Service found: These Windows services are started:

Service found:

Service found:    Application Information

Service found:    aswbIDSAgent

Service found:    Avast Antivirus

Service found:    Background Tasks Infrastructure Service

Service found:    Base Filtering Engine

Service found:    CNG Key Isolation

Service found:    COM+ Event System

Service found:    Connected Devices Platform Service

Service found:    Connected Devices Platform User Service_2f2f13e

Service found:    Connected User Experiences and Telemetry

Service found:    Contact Data_2f2f13e

Service found:    CoreMessaging

Service found:    Credential Manager

Service found:    Cryptographic Services

Service found:    Data Sharing Service

Service found:    Data Usage

Service found:    DCOM Server Process Launcher

Service found:    Delivery Optimization

Service found:    Device Association Service

Service found:    DHCP Client

Service found:    Diagnostic Policy Service

Service found:    Diagnostic Service Host

Service found:    Distributed Link Tracking Client

Service found:    DNS Client

Service found:    Geolocation Service

Service found:    Human Interface Device Service

Service found:    IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules

....rest of NET START LIST
```

I've tried quite a few things to make it work, but the output is almost always as above. Any help would be great.

Comment: You couldn't just read through your own code line by line? `list1.append(line)` you're appending every line to this `list1` and then when your condition hits you're printing each line in this list.

Comment: You are always executing list1.append(line) regardless if there if you find either substr value. Then if you do happen to find either subset value in the current line, you reprint all previous lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some logical errors in your code. First, `tstring=substr1+substr2` produces a string `'NetworkDiagnostic'` (the sum of two substrings). Second, `line.find(tstring)` returns `-1` if the substring is not found, and `-1` is `True`. Third, the variable `stop` is never used.

Here's a possible solution:

```
with open(path1) as file:
    for line in file:
       if substr1 in line or substr2 in line:
            print("Service found: ", line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for line in file:
    if 'Network' in line or 'Diagnostic' in line:
        print('Service found:', line)
```

It's pretty hard to understand what you are doing in your present code. `list1` is not needed, and you shouldn't be iterating through the whole of `list1` and printing it every time you find `'Network'` or `'Diagnostic'`.